# Do we still need to use guzzle if we will use ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, api

Since on using AJAX, js will mostly be the one responsible on the front end. With that in mind.

If we use guzzle the flow will be like the one below.

1. View(request)->Ajax->controller(call api)->api_controller(return response)->controller(return response)->view

If we don't use guzzle then it will be like this

2. View(request)->Ajax->api_controller(return response)->view

So, aint it better for ajax to call the api_controller instead of the view_controller first?

Comment: guzzle and ajax doesnt go together. why call the api route from your controller since you are already in a controller that has the same access as the api controller one....

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.

Comment: In my experience. Only use Guzzle from controller if you want to access external APIs as **a part** of your own API call.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.